# Comparing elements of a list to an integer without using for or while loops (teacher wants us to use reduce nd map)

Tags: python

I'm trying to compare the elements of a list to a lower and upper limit without using for and while loops. My teacher wants us to use the map and reduce functions. The issue is that the upper limit is a parameter tied to a function and I can't use it in another function unless I make it a global variable (which kinda defeats the purpose of it being a parameter). With that being said, the comparison has to be done in the function in which my constant h is in. However, since I have to use map and reduce to somehow cycle through the indexes of my list, I have to exit the function and go to another one (since map and reduce use functions). The code is the following:

```
def fct(n,l,h):
    nX = n * l ; nY = n * h
    t = list(map(lambda n: "#",range(nX * nY)))
```

From here, I would like to compare the elements in t to my limits:

```
if 0 <= n <= h-1:
    #Do something
elif etc...
```

Here, n is the value being compared (in other words n = t[i]). Is there anyway to obtain n using map and reduce?

Comment: Within your function `fct`, your lambda functions can still access the variables `n`, `l`, and `h` unless you've defined another variable within the lambda with the same name like you did with `n`.

Comment: in your code , all the elements of t would be the string of "#" and then you want to compare it with numbers as in  `0 < t[i] < h-1 `. if it wasn't just for demonstration here, it won't make sense otherwise

Answer (score 0):

depends on what would be the  `do somethng` part:

```
def fct(n,l,h):
    nX = n * l ; nY = n * h
    t = list(map(lambda n: n,range(nX * nY)))
    return reduce(lambda a,b : a+b, map(lambda a : 0 <= a <= h-1,t))
```

I imagined #Do something is sum of list elements

Answer (score 0):

```
def operation(item, lower, upper):
    if lower <= item <= upper-1:
        ...
        # Do something
        # return value

    # do other things, return other values

def iterate(numbers, lower, upper):
    return list( map( lambda item: operation(item, lower, upper), numbers) )
```

from my understanding of what you wrote, you will be iterating through items in a list (presumably of integers) and on each item checking whether it fits into given lower and upper bounds. Depending on whether it fits you'll perform one action, if not another. Break it down into seperate functions, one function that will perform the comparison and then act on it and another that will iterate through the list, applying that function to each item. You can use map to iterate through each number in the list, applying the operation function to each element.